# Palantir Foundry cannot save files in code repository

Tags: palantir-foundry

I've made some changes in my code repository, but cannot save the files.

When closing the tab, Foundry warns me that the changes might be lost (which they are, I've had a similar issue before). At the same time, the Code Assist is running indefinitetly "Saving changes...".

Also, I cannot build my datasets, since the button is greyed out. When commiting files, the procedure also runs indefinitetly.

This also happen, if I completely reset, loose my changes and make new ones. Seems the Code Assist is completely broken for me.

What do I do here? I don't want to loose my changes, but cannot proceed further at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible that you've had that tab open for a long time and that your token has expired? If you open Foundry in a new tab does it prompt you to log in again?

Comment: A trick to get you unblocked: duplicate your tab (so open the repository in another fresh tab), ctrl+a and copy paste your changes that were unsaved, commit again.

Comment: The token was not expired. Unfortunately, the trick did not solve my problem. The new tab has the same issues again.